# how to Update duplicate rows without primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table with NO Primary Key.

```
name      age       sex
a         12        m
b         61        m
c         23        f
d         12        m
a         12        m
a         12        m
f         14        f
```

i have exactly 3 similar rows-row-1,row-5 and row-6.
i want to update row-5 without affecting row-1 and row-6.
Pls help me out, how to achieve this.

Comment: Why update 5 and not 1 or 6? Why not update 1 and not 5 or 6? Is there some hidden logic here you use in your own mind to differentiate between 1, 5 and 6? If so, the solution probably lies in that logic.

Comment: I think the most obvious answer to this is: Add a Primary Key.

Comment: you can depend on row_number() which gives unique id for each row in SQL Server

Comment: *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table* ....

Comment: What is the table related to?  Why would you have three records with the same information?  By the way, it is really bad practice to not have a primary key.

Answer (score 3):

Your real problem is that you have no row numbers, and no way to distiguish identical rows. If your data is still in the order in which it was inserted you have simply been lucky so far. SQL Server gives no guarantees of row ordering and could randomize the order without notice. To preserve your ordering you can add an identity column to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE TableWithNoPrimaryKey
ADD RowNum int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to use ROW_NUMBER function in SQL as this duplicates can be spread over thousands of record.
ROW_NUMBER is use to get the row number with OVER clause and as the storage of such data is non clustred its not possible to delete.
The only option is to add some identity or unique column to the table and then delete the special record and if you dont want table with the new index or new column you can delete that cloumn from the table.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do what you wish. It is not recommended though.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GETDATE())
    FROM [table]
)
UPDATE cte
SET age = age + 1
WHERE (RowNum = 5)
AND (name = 'a' AND age = 12 AND sex = 'm');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have considered your table name as T1 and updated one of the rows. I don't want to order the result set but still want to generate the row numbers, so I used a dummy subquery - Select 0. Below query works in Oracle and IBM Netezza. You can try using rowid if it exists in SQL SERVER or any other equivalent to rowid should work.

```
UPDATE T1 SET name = a1, age = 21, sex = 'm'
FROM (SELECT name, age, sex, rowid,
row_number() over(partition by name, age, sex ORDER BY(SELECT 0)) as rn
FROM T1)A
WHERE T1.name = A.name 
AND T1.age = A.age
AND T1.sex = A.sex
AND T1.rowid = A.rowid 
AND A.rn = 1;
```